# Gravity center not working in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have LinearLayout horizontal orientation.Height is 32 dp.I try to insert textview's text in center position,[image: but i have like this result]

This is my source

```
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/departure_icon"
                        android:id="@+id/departure_img"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/departure_day_large"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/departure_day_large"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:text="28"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="32dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see i can't insert 28 in center positon,both imageview and textview's height is 32 dp, and i would like to insert my textview center.How i can horizontal align with ImageView?

Comment: Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` for `TextView`

Comment: Not working  @ Piyush

Comment: If your linearlayout height is `32` than apply `match_parent` for `ImageView` and `TextView` also set `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` for `LinearLayout` @Baggio

Answer (score 1):

You've specified `android:textSize="32dp"` - this is the issue.
Make your `TextView`'s and `LinearLayout`'s height `wrap_content`.

Additionally, you'd better specify text sizes with `sp` - scale dependent pixel. If you want your `TextView` to be specifically that much sp, than you have to make your `LinearLayout`'s height `wrap_content`, because you cannot now how much height would your `TextView` take depending on device's screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/departure_icon"
            android:id="@+id/departure_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/departure_day_large"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departure_day_large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="28"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not working .Maybe problem is textsize,.Textsize is 32 dp and weight also is 32 dp @azizbekian

Answer (score 0):

Change TextView layout_width = match_parent

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/departure_icon"
                android:id="@+id/departure_img"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/departure_day_large"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/departure_day_large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:text="28"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="32dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes, 
I added your piece of code to RecyclerView and worked as expected

Comment: @Baggio Check my comment

Comment: I don't know what is a wrong but i tested your code and i have same problem @ patrick

Comment: @Baggio have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your parent layout with a relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/departure_icon"
            android:id="@+id/departure_img"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/departure_day_large"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/departure_day_large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="28"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```